# Induced emf in a circular moving loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

The net change in flux is zero throughout the circular loop so the induced emf must also be zero. If we consider the case of motional emf then the situation would be something like this [image] So the net emf would still be zero but the book says its 2Bvr...How is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The induced emf *around* the loop is zero. So there is no current *around* the loop. But this does not prevent there being an emf *across* the loop, and equal currents through the upper and lower halves of the circle from left to right : ie clockwise in the upper half and anti-clockwise in the lower half.